# visual studio 2012 crashes with breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

This just recently started happening. I've tried repairing Visual Studio which didn't work.  Whenever I try to debug with a breakpoint Visual Studio crashes. I've tried using a completely new solution and resetting my user info with `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`. It seems to crash when "loading symbols for msvcr110d.dll." Debugging with no breakpoints (which is rather useless) seems to work just fine.

I've also tried running Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Also debugging C# projects work just fine (breakpoints and all).

Comment: How recently?  Have you checked your system log to see what system updates have been applied near the time it started acting up?

Comment: See if this helps: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/breakpoint-crash-26586.aspx

Comment: Do you have debug symbols for msvcr110d.dll (as in a "msvcr110d.pdb") on your machine? If so, could they be out of sync?

Comment: Paddy, I'm honestly not sure because I've been working in C# for a while and haven't needed to debug C++. I tried editing the options on the link you gave and it still crashes. Mats, where would it be located and how would I check if they're out of sync?

Comment: This question requires a better diagnostic of the crash to be answerable.  Workarounds are disabling unmanaged debugging (Project + Properties, Debug tab) and disabling the symbol server (Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols)

Comment: The symbols server is already disabled and I don't see the unmanaged debugging option in the debug tab (went to Project->Properties and then the debug section). How can I give a better diagnostic? What more do you need? (I also tried reinstalling VS11 completely and the issue still occurs)

Comment: I think I have the same issue. The crash is more in placing the BP than breaking on it, as if I place a BP in a method not called in my loop, VS2012 will crash anyway.

Comment: I found a temporary fix: go to tools->options->debugging->edit and continue and then enable native edit and continue. VS11 uses new debugging technology so enabling this falls back to what it was before. This worked for me, however the problem I had before just disappeared (not sure why) check the configuration of the addons or settings another pc you have that has it working. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: When you disabled the symbol server, did you also clear out the symbol cache?  Perhaps you've got a corrupted PDB for that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enabling Native Edit and Continue (Options -> Debugging -> Edit and Continue -> Enable native Edit and Continue)